# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'session' not found'

Tags: laravel, session

local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'session' not found' in D:\b7c5702095ce08f079bddb25840d3c122657b351.php:60

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I guess you should use `Session` instead of `session`, mind the uppercase `S`

Comment: What @Michel told is correct, if you want more info, show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use correct class name and use it with namespace:

```
\Season::
```

Or add a namespace at the top of your class:

```
use Session;
```

And then use the class without namespace:

```
Session::
```